# How do I deal with random effects terms specified in formula?

Tags: lme4, random-effects

This is my following script:

```
library(lme4)
library(RColorBrewer) # needed for some extra colors in one of the graphs
library(lmerTest)# to get p-value estimations that are not part of the standard lme4 packages
lear<-read.csv("C:/Users/Liat/Documents/R/liat_data.csv")
colnames(lear) = c("participant","examiner", "date", "sex", "age", "age_group", "Hearing_status", "compression", "first 5", "last 5", "learning")
names(lear)

model <- lme4::lmer( learning ~ sex+age+Hearing_status,data = lear)
summary(model)
```

I get the following error: `Error: No random effects terms specified in formula`

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what variable you want to specify as your grouping variable, you need to add in a `|` to your equation. For example, if you wanted to group your participants by  do the following `model<- lme4::lmer(learning~ sex+(sex | <id variable>)+age+Hearing_status, data=lear)`

Check out the documentation[lme4 cran documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf)